# Problems choosing the right answer in inequality with variable in denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This question was asked in an exam and I solved it taking into consideration if the denominator is positive or negative. However, there was only one correct answer ($r>0.04$). I have been looking at videos, but I can´t realize why there is only one answer. This is the problem:

Solve for $r$:

$175 >  \frac{7}{0.08 - r}$

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is reasonable to take into consideration the sign of the denominator (since a negative denominator on the right hand side gives a negative ratio, and thus satisfies the inequality).  However note that those values $r$ which achieve this are *greater than* $0.04$ also, so the "one correct answer" incorporates these.  Perhaps the only qualification we should add is $r\neq 0.08$ to avoid division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $0.08-r>0$,
$$175(0.08-r)>7 \\ 14-175r>7 \\ 175r<7 \\r<\frac{7}{175}\\r<0.04$$

If $0.08 -r<0$, 
$$175(0.08-r)<7 \\ 14-175r<7 \\ 175r>7 \\r>\frac{7}{175}\\r>0.04$$
But we also have $0.08 -r<0$, therefore $r>0.08$.

Comment: I think it's not fair to fix the post after viewing of my right solution. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$175-\frac{7}{0.08-r}>0$$ or
$$\frac{25r-1}{r-0.08}>0,$$
which gives the answer: $r<0.04$ or $r>0.08$.